# Aurora 5 with .Net selenium does not open listen port 7055

Tags: firefox, selenium, webdriver

I'm trying to automate Firefox aurora 5 with selenium 2.6 (I can't use a newer version because its a modified Firefox version, and making the changes in a newer aurora is a big issue).

I'm calling:

```
FirefoxBinary binary = new FirefoxBinary(aurora_exe_path);
FirefoxDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Aurora is being executed, but selenium fails to connect firefox WebDriver. I noticed that Aurora does not open a listen port on 7055, but I just can't understand why, or how to fix it.

Thanks a lot for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only way I could get it to run is using selenium server.

I executed selenium server (listens to port 4444), and then I just used DefaultSelenium class:

```
Selenium selenium = new DefaultSelenium("localhost", 4444, "*firefox "+aurora_full_path, browserURL);
```

This way, the selenium client connects to the server which automates aurora successfully.